# ACS and facebook login -> display=touch is broken?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, oauth, touch, acs

I'm using ACS to auth against Facebook.  Before this week, I could add display=touch to the end of the URL ACS is providing.  Now when I do this I'm getting a "HTTP 500 Internal Server Error".

Any ideas?  The URL is something like:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myid&redirect_uri=myreturnurl&scope=email&display=touch

I've tried m.facebook.com with the same result.

Again, this worked before... and if I remove display=touch (or change it to display=popup) everything is fine.

I want this to display on a WP7 app, thus the touch :)

Thanks
SR

Update: Docs say "Display mode in which to render the Dialog. Can be page, popup, iframe, touch, or wap.".   Touch and wap return a "HTTP 500 Internal server error".

Comment: fixed by facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/287213021307964

Answer (score 1):

Also breaks my app and even Seesmic. It needs to be fixed by FB.
I created a bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/287213021307964

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself a few days ago. It appears to be a change Facebook has made on their end, despite what their docs say.

I tried using display=popup instead, which worked for me.

Comment: Yep, popup works. The problem I'm running into is it's for a mobile app - and popup, while it minimizes what’s shown, does the “big” version of the page. So the user has to zoom in, click around on fields, other awkward stuff.

Touch always brought back the mobile optimized version of the login.  I assume there’s another way to do this, or else others would be screaming about this apparent break in the FB API…

-Greg